# Why does concurrent.futures executor map throw error when using with concurrent.futures.wait in slurm

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, slurm

I am submitting a .py file to Slurm. the following code describes it. after submitting to Slurm, I am getting an error. the code runs fine when I run on the node instead of Slurm sbmission. any leads?

```
def do_work_item(index):
    some code
   
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as ex:

    not_done= ex.map(do_work_item,list(range(start,stop)),chunksize=x)
              
    done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait(
        not_done,
        return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
```

error in slurm .out

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/cm/local/apps/slurm/var/spool/job7335937/slurm_script", line 276, in <module> done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait( File "/home/hbpvinju/anaconda3/envs/satpy/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 291, in wait with _AcquireFutures(fs): File "/home/hbpvinju/anaconda3/envs/satpy/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 151, in __enter__ future._condition.acquire() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_condition'`

I tried to run in the Python interface which worked normally. I expect it to work on slurm for bulk multithread processing